# powershell for loop - Nmap

Tags: powershell, nmap

I am scanning some internal networks from a windows server currently a subnet at a time. I will be automating this at some stage but am not that familiar with powershell and am learning programming. Was after some guidance from the community.

The logic i have so far is

```
file = nmap_subnets.txt
scan = (nmap.exe -sV -T3 -O -F -version-light')

for subnet in file:
    scan ('-oN $subnet.txt')

exit
```

nmap_subnets.txt will just contain one subnet per line ie 192.168.1.0/25
I then want for each subnet on a line use that subnet as the filename for the output from -oN

If the logic is wrong im open to any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$file = ".\nmap_subnets.txt"
ForEach($range in get-content $file) 
{
    & nmap.exe -sV -T3 -O -F -version-light -oN $range
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the code above, it seems that the subnets.txt needs to be in CIDR notation for nmap to successfully launch the command. But the output for -oN needs to have the / removed as windows doesnt like that in filenames.  Looking into a strip function now.

Comment: you might just need to escape the /